# Speed of photons in Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation relative to the earth (or solar system)

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, cosmic-microwave-background

At https://living-universe.com/questions-and-answers/absolute-motion-of-photons-in-the-2-7cbr/, we are told that the Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation (CMBR) is propagating relative to the earth (or solar system) at the speed of 375 km/sec. If we treat the frame that the earth (or solar system) is moving in as an inertial frame, then the speed of the photons in the CMBR relative to this inertial frame is only 375 km/sec. But 375 km/sec is far slower than the speed of light, 3 x 10^8 m/sec, or 3x10^5 km/sec. Therefore, the speed of the photons in the CMBR relative to the chosen inertial frame (earth or solar system) is about 1000 times slower than the expected speed of light. How does this difference in speed square with special relativity which says the speed of light (or photons) relative to any inertial frame is the constant, c, which is 3 x 10^8 m/sec? Or can we avoid this discrepancy with special relativity by saying that the frame in which the earth (or solar system) is moving is not an inertial frame? Even if we say that, will that be enough to account for the great difference between the speed of the photons in the CMBR relative to the chosen inertial frame (earth or solar system) and c?

Comment: On the website it says "*The Living Universe* is alternative theory of physics". In short, this website is non-mainstream physics.

Comment: @Jonas - Even so, there is a valid question here. How can we move at 375 km/sec with respect to the CMB? The CMB is made out of photons which move at c with respect to everything. There is a misconception that can be cleared up.

Comment: I seems to me that this website is just plain wrong – photons from the CMB should thus move at $c$ towards us.

Comment: There is nonetheless the CMB Dipole who show that the earth moves relative to the CMB.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux your statement requires the assumption that the CMB sources don't move relative to each other, in suitable coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the principle of the constancy of the speed of light with the phenomenon of relativistic Doppler shift. Although the speed of light is always the same, the frequency of light can be increased or reduced as a consequence of relative motion between the observer and the source of the light. When we examine the CMB, we find it is redshifted in one direction and blue-shifted in another, suggesting that we are moving relative to it. That motion is motion relative to a the frame in which the CMB originated, not relative to the individual photons in the CMB, as they all move at a constant speed of c.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. That sounds sensible to me.